# `map!': private method called for String (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I tried to write a private function that will take in a single token and return the given token without white space or punctuation, for example:

```
normalize_token(" cat.")
# => "cat"
```

I then defined an array of tokens that have punctuation and white space:

```
["a.", "      b...."]
```

which I'd like to map over using my defined function. I expect a new object returned, which looks like:

```
["a", "b"]
```

Here is a small snippet of code:

```
private def normalize_token(token)
  token.gsub(/\W/, ' ') # does the same thing as [^A-Za-z0-9_]
end

["a.", "      b...."].map!(&:normalize_token)
```

I get:

> `map!': private method`normalize_token' called for "a.":String
>   (NoMethodError)

Any help or even an explanation of what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing the method reference, pass a block:

```
private def normalize_token(token)
  token.gsub(/\W/, ' ') # does the same thing as [^A-Za-z0-9_]
end

["a.", "      b...."].map! {|token| normalize_token token}
```

This will leave white space in your strings, so you might want to `chomp!` them or change your `gsub` to `gsub(/\w/, '')`

**Explanation**

The first problem is that `normalize_token` is private. You can get around that by making it public or by `send`ing it as @alex mentioned.

The second problem however is more subtle.

By passing the method reference, you essentially have the following

```
["a.", "      b...."].map! {|token| token.send :normalize_token }
```

Running this will result in the following error message:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))
```

`map!` will not pass the mapped value to `normalize_token` as an argument. (notice that the `send` has your mapped value as a *receiver* but not as an *argument*.) Instead, by using a block with a variable declared, we can get around this by passing the mapped value as an argument explicitly in the block.

Comment: This worked. Can you provide a small explanation as to why 

"passing a block"

fixes this?

Comment: Updated my answer with more explanation.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Quick note on `&:` - it accomplishes the same thing as `{|i| ...}` by using & to call to_proc on the :object, then passes it as a block to the method - so in order to use it, whatever follows `&:` needs to be defined on whatever object is being passed to `map!`.

Here's an example, cracking open the `String` class to define it there:

```
class String
  def normalize_token
    self.gsub(/\W/, ' ')
  end
end
```

Which will let you use your original `["a.", "      b...."].map!(&:normalize_token)`.
Not a great idea to do stuff like this in real life, since you'd probably want normalize_token to be defined in whatever class is responsible for generating these strings. But it should get you started.

Comment: Ok, I think I follow this. Thank you alex!